# Why does a Kalman filter perform poorly in non linear systems?

Tags: nonlinear-system, kalman-filter

I am new to learning kalman filter. I could get the gist of system.
For example  tracking an object in 2D $x-y$ space, you predict the next location using a series of linear equation based on the Newtonian equation of motion. Then you take a measurement , convert our prediction to the same unit as measurement compute the residue and select the estimated state part way between predicted and measurement values. However they also told that these are only good for linear systems, but fails when dealing with non linear systems.

Clarification needed

1. I would like to know the difference between linear system and non linear system.
   Is it analogous to a car going in straight line vs car taking a sudden sharp turn? As equation required to represent both trajectory are linear vs non linear?
2. If my assumption is correct, then we can use the necessary process noise  to account for same right? So why do we have a special class Kalman filters the focus on non linear systems?

Please forgive me if the question is dumb, Please explain to me like a 5 year old !

Thank You

Comment: The Kalman filter is based on estimating the best value of some hidden variables $Y$, based on the observables $X$ and its standard deviation. It's much easier to predict the mean and standard deviation of $Y$ from $X$ if $Y$ depends linearly on $X$. One just uses standard formulae. For non-linear systems, one has to work out this dependence explicitly for it to work properly.

Comment: I think your confusion is understanding the difference between a linear and nonlinear system. If you have a nonlinear system, you simply cannot use a Kalman filter because you can’t write the process and observation models in the required form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A drawing of why Kalman Filter is an issue in nonlinear systems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGorp.png)

It is quite an old question but I still think this answer will help many. The picture that I made above explains it quite well. We know that the most significant assumption before we apply KF is that the system noise and the process noise are Gaussian. When applying KF to a linear system, the assumption remains at the output. It is scaled most likely, but still holds its Gaussian character. However, if your system is not linear, the preassumed Gaussian noise is distorted at the output. Depending on "how much nonlinear" is your system, that assumption breaks even worse such that KF estimation means nothing.